# adjusting the menu to cover the menu width

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I have a horizantal menu using a thrid party control. The width of the menu is 100% and I have to arrange the menu items so that they cover the entire width of the page and are adjusted automatically, but somehow last menu item is scrolled to another line if the screen is small and if the screen is big then they are adjusted on the same line. Below is my code. How can I make the menuitems so that they adjust accordingly with the width of the screen.

```
  <div style="background-color:#8e2826; margin-left:15%; margin-right:17%;   color:#8e2826">
       <uc1:NavigationBar ID="NavigationBar" runat="server"  />
  </div>
```

and the code for navigation bar is

```
<MainMenu ID="RadMenu1" runat="server" EnableRoundedCorners="false" EnableShadows="false"
            Height="25px" Width="100%" BackColor="#8e2826" BorderColor="#8e2826" BorderWidth="0" width="100%" >

                <MenuItem Text="Query" BackColor="#8e2826" ForeColor="#cea70b"  Font-Names="Calibri" width="12.5%" >

                <MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Text="Metrics" BackColor="#8e2826" ForeColor="#cea70b"  Font-Names="Calibri" width="12.5%" >

                <MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Text="Reports" BackColor="#8e2826" ForeColor="#cea70b"  Font-Names="Calibri" width="12.5%" >

                <MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Text="Exports" BackColor="#8e2826" ForeColor="#cea70b"  Font-Names="Calibri" width="12.5%" >

                <MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Text="Imports" BackColor="#8e2826" ForeColor="#cea70b"  Font-Names="Calibri" width="12.5%" >

                <MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Text="Web Service" BackColor="#8e2826" ForeColor="#cea70b"  Font-Names="Calibri" width="12.5%" >

                <MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Text="Versions &Fixes" BackColor="#8e2826" ForeColor="#cea70b" Font-Names="Calibri" width="12.5%" >

                <MenuItem>

            </Items>
        </MainMenu>

below is the style sheet

<style type="text/css">

 .style1
 {



    display:inline-block; zoom:1; *display:inline; 


 }
</style>
```

any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Could you post the relevant CSS?

Comment: on a related note, AHH!! inline style!!

Comment: <style type="text/css">

     .style1
     {
      
    
       
        display:inline-block; zoom:1; *display:inline; 
         
         
     }
    </style>

Answer (score 0):

There is a jQuery plugin, that could od that for you.

https://github.com/lukaszklis/AutoScalingMenu